# How do I correctly select several rows in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a users table in MySQL. The table has an email field. I have an array of hundreds of emails in PHP. How do I select all the records in the table where the email id is in the array? 
Bear in mind that I know I can do:

```
  SELECT * FROM users WHERE 
  email IN (
email1@gmail.com, email2@gmail.com,
 email3@gmail.com, email4@gmail.com, 
email5@gmail.com);
```

How would using the MySQL '`IN`' statement with hundreds of emails affect the performance of my query? is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Better way? No. This is the way to select all rows that match an item in the list. Performance.. Have you tried?

Comment: The alternative would be to create a temp table with all the emails and `JOIN` it. It may be faster for a large (500+) amount of emails, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Where is your list of e-mails stored ?

Comment: @Vatev option will speedup your query !

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new (maybe temporary) table from your array and then use joins.

Another way would be to select only single mail addresses in combination with one single prepared statement (`SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?`). This does require executing queries inside of a loop, which one should avoid in general. Since the query is only parsed once on preparation and only the selecting data is transferred on each execution of the prepared statement, this might run fast nevertheless.
This might be a solution one should take into account especially since very very long queries tend to produce unwanted side effects (like taking MySQL a bunch of time to just parse the statement).

Answer (score 0):

The performance are pretty much the same:

```
mysql> select benchmark(10000000000,'SELECT * FROM test3 WHERE (email = ''email1@gmail.com'' or email = ''email2@gmail.com'' or email = ''email3@gmail.com'' or email = ''email4@gmail.com'' or email = ''email5@gmail.com'')');
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| benchmark(10000000000,'SELECT * FROM test3 WHERE (email = ''email1@gmail.com'' or email = ''email2@gmail.com'' or email = ''email3@gmail.com'' or email = ''email4@gmail.com'' or email = ''email5@gmail.com'')') |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (1 min 7.70 sec)

mysql> select benchmark(10000000000,'SELECT * FROM test3 WHERE email IN (''email1@gmail.com'', ''email2@gmail.com'', ''email3@gmail.com'', ''email4@gmail.com'', ''email5@gmail.com'')');
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| benchmark(10000000000,'SELECT * FROM test3 WHERE email IN (''email1@gmail.com'', ''email2@gmail.com'', ''email3@gmail.com'', ''email4@gmail.com'', ''email5@gmail.com'')') |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                                                                                                          0 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (1 min 7.75 sec)
```

Second try:

```
mysql> select benchmark(1000000000,'SELECT * FROM test3 WHERE email IN (1,2,3,4,5)');
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| benchmark(1000000000,'SELECT * FROM test3 WHERE email IN (1,2,3,4,5)') |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                      0 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (6.72 sec)

mysql> select benchmark(1000000000,'SELECT * FROM test3 WHERE email=1 or email=2 or email=3 or email=4 or email=5');
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| benchmark(1000000000,'SELECT * FROM test3 WHERE email=1 or email=2 or email=3 or email=4 or email=5') |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                                     0 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (6.64 sec)
```

I will add that the WHERE...OR is faster than a WHERE...IN.

Comment: Probably because MySQL does not have to rewrite the IN to a bunch of OR's.... Which, to my knowledge, is what it would do...

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to use a relational solution. For example, instead of trying to pass in a list of emails, maintain a `subscriptions` table and a `user_subscriptions` table to maintain which users belong to which mailing lists. Then your query is an efficient:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
INNER JOIN user_subscriptions
WHERE 
  user_subscriptions.subscriptionID = 1
```

Comment: This `user-subscriptions` with the hyphen might be interpreted as a mathematical operation. It's best to use underscores.